# Remaining ginger bug

Tags: fermentation, yeast, beer, ginger-beer, ginger

This is the first time I will make a ginger bug and the process seems very simple but my question is. How long can I keep feeding my ginger bug and if I will be using that bug to make ginger beer  what happens when I run out of the culture, can I add more water?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Some information here, but not a complete answer: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/22204/ginger-bug-expansion

Answer (score 3):

When you use some of the ginger bug you simply add back the amount of liquid afterwards.

You can keep it going for as long as you want, just keep feeding it ginger and sugar at regular intervals and it will keep bubbling along for as long as you want it!

Tip: if you don't need the ginger bug for a while you can put it in the fridge and only feed it once a week